# Android- create android assets with photoshop

Tags: android

I am not designer and I dont know if I should ask this question here or not , but I need to create some assets to my application.

what I need to know what is the psd file should be to export `drawable-xxxhdpi` , `drawable-xxhdpi`

> PSD FILE SIZE

After long research I find to export **xxxhdpi** assets psd file should be *1440 w * 2560 h* , and to export **xxhdpi** file should be *1080 w * 1920 h*. ***I need some one correct me if this wrong.***

> Prepare assets to export

After create my images (assets) , if it was group of layer I should merge it to single layer , press Ctrl + A (select all) . then create new file with Preset type custom or Clipboard
 [image]

> Export Criteria

To export assets , I save image with Save for web option First export will be with the default size mean if I choose to make my file to be 1440 w * 2560 h then my default export will be xxxhdpi .

[image]

then to export other sizes I will change percentage to

```
                                xxhdpi to 0.75 
                                 xhdpi to 0.5
                                 hdpi  to 0.37
                                 mdpi  to 0.25
```

according to [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

[image]

Comment: I do think this is a good question. However I'm exporting my image large enough and use this online tool: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

Comment: No, it's simpler: Make the bigger image (for xxxhdpi density). Then scale it DOWN accordingly. No need to save for web: this is PNG, not GIF. I also never use the 72 dpi density: I use a per device density (640, 480, 320, 240, 160, 120 dpi). When possible, I avoid pngs and use svgs or drawables - Or Unicode characters (which are conceptually similar to SVGs, since fonts are vectorial)

Comment: how can I export SVG with photoshop , please write answer with more details

Comment: dpi is an indication of density, not of number of pixels. you can have 1080p on a xxxhdpi or on a mdpi, depending on the screen size.

Comment: No, you can't export SVGs in PhotoShop. But you can draw/edit them in Inkscape

Comment: @njzk2 Yes, I know. I work in px depending on the dpi scale factor. (0.75, 1, 1.5, 2, 3, 4).

Comment: @FrankN.Stein My comment was directed to the OP because of the statement `I find to export xxxhdpi assets psd file should be *1440 w * 2560 h*`

Answer (score 1):

There is a great tool (jar file) - resizer that will make it easy for you.

https://github.com/asystat/Final-Android-Resizer

Comment: thank you for answer but first is file psd size correct 1440 w * 2560 h  ?

Comment: I hope it will clarify things for you.
http://vinsol.com/blog/2014/11/20/tips-for-designers-from-a-developer/